# How to parse Json To XML?

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, wcf, rest

I have a Json which I want to parse into XML, I am using "Newton-King" liabrary and its method JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json)

Json:

```
{
   "ISDCode":"TestISD",
   "retailerCode":"RT148",
   "count":"2",
   "salesdata":[
      {
         "Serial":"3544334444",
         "CustomerPhone":"98234234234",
         "CustomerName":"Name1",
         "CustomerInfoID":"1",
         "TimeStamp":"/Date(1224043200000)/",
         "Latitude":"10.3456",
         "Longitude":"8.3453"
      }
   ]
}
```

but it is giving me error
"JSON root object has multiple properties. The root object must have a single property in order to create a valid XML document. Consider specifing a DeserializeRootElementName."

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Wrap it in one more javascript object, e.g. {foo:{ "ISDCode": etc...

Comment: @MatthewMartin why not add it as an answer? Then it's clearer that it's a solution and not a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in one more javascript object, e.g. {foo:{ "ISDCode": etc...

XML needs a root element, but JSON doesn't.

Comment: Now just have to wait until the OP marks it as such... tum tee tum